# Cakephp: group not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Here is the Model that I've written:

```
public function getMockTestResultDetails($studentID){

        $mockTestResults = array();
        $mockTestResults = $this->find('all',array(
            'joins' => array(

                array(
                    'table' => 'exam',
                    'alias' => 'exm',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array('StudentExam.TEMPLATEEXAM=exm.ID' ),
                )

            ),
            'fields' => array('exm.ENTRANCEEXAM', 'exm.NAME','count(StudentExam.TEMPLATEEXAM)' ,'StudentExam.IMPROVEMENT_INDEX' ,`StudentExam.EXAM_COMPLETED_ON`,'StudentExam.PHASE_ONE',
'StudentExam.PHASE_TWO','StudentExam.PHASE_THREE','StudentExam.PHASE_FOUR','StudentExam.PHASE_INTERN'),

            //'group' => array(`StudentExam.TEMPLATEEXAM`),
            'conditions' => array('exm.EXAM_TYPE' => 'MOCK','StudentExam.STUDENT' => $studentID,'StudentExam.STATUS' => 'COMPLETED'),


        ));

        return $mockTestResults;
    }
```

When I comment the line where 'group' is it works and I get a output but it is partial/incomplete output. I must use group to obtain the right answer. The same query when executed on phpmyadmin it works fine but it is not working in cakephp. Am I missing something here or what please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Are those quotes correct there? Shouldn't it be `'` instead of `?

Comment: Oh my god what a typo. Thank you so much skywalker you saved my day

Comment: Copy/paste, mother of all programmer mistakes :)